# Pass image through intent using URI to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, uri

I am a beginner in programming. I am trying to create Meme generator app. I have got to a point where I display an array of images in a GridView, user can click on one image and it will take them to a new activity where user can enter top and bottom text.

I would appreciate your help with below based on the code I have.

- **A)** I am trying to convert a Relative Layout (two TextViews and one ImageView) in a bitmap. Is the code correct?
- **- B)** I want to send    bitmap created from Relative Layout to    FullImage.java activity when    user clicks on Create button. Is the 
  code correct you think?
- **- C)** When Create  button is clicked by the user, currently I get "Failed Binder    Transaction". I think its because I am passing an
  image. I tried to    understand and use how to pass URI but was not
  successful. I tried to    find snippet on SO and other blogs but was 
  not successful. Is it    possible for you to give me detail code? (As
  a beginner, Ill be    thankful!)

DetailsActivity.java

```
package com.jobaka.www.jobaka;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Psp on 2016-03-03.
 */
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etTop, etBottom;
    TextView tvTop, tvBottom;
    Button bCreate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details_activity);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int id = intent.getIntExtra("id", -1);
        if(id != -1){
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), id);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }else{

        }

        //imageUri = Uri.parse(extras.getString("imageUri"));

        etTop = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTop);
        tvTop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTop);
        etTop.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                tvTop.setText(s.toString());
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count, int after) {}

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) {}
        });

        etBottom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBottom);
        tvBottom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBottom);
        etBottom.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable sb) {
                tvBottom.setText(sb.toString());
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence sb, int start,int count, int after) {}

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence sb, int start,int before, int count) {}
        });

        bCreate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCreate);
        bCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.iFrame);
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(),
                        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                view.draw(canvas);

                Intent sendImage = new Intent(DetailsActivity.this, FullImage.class);
                sendImage.putExtra("pic", bitmap);
                startActivity(sendImage);
            }
        });




    }


}
```

FullImage.java

```
package com.jobaka.www.jobaka;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class FullImage extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView finalimage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_image);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Intent startingIntent = getIntent();
        String whatYouSent = startingIntent.getStringExtra("pic");
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("pic");
        finalimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivFull);
        finalimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your FullImageActivity, do this to retrieve the bitmap

```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("pic");
```

This is because the bitmap class in android implements parcelable.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

Comment: I removed following lines. And added what you gave. Still nothing happens when I click on Create button on DeatailsActivity.java. It should take me to FullImage activity. Also, any examples you can point out to me where image is passed using uri? That is the second problem I think. Thank you for your prompt reply.                                                                                              //String whatYouSent = startingIntent.getStringExtra("pic");
 //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("pic");